# Prometheus query to get the consumer lag increase in the last 5 minutes

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, kafka-exporter

I'm using Kafka exporter to monitor the Kafka metrics which is then queried in prometheus.
I have a Kafka topic with 3 consumer groups, these 3 consumer groups are used by 3 different services. I am trying to write a query to have an alert when either of these consumer group lag increases beyond the average lag.

The query I have so far:

```
kafka_consumer_group_lag{group_id=~"consumer_group.*"} > avg_over_time(kafka_consumer_group_lag{group_id=~"consumer_group.*"}[5m])
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure how to form the calculation to get this.
Can someone help me in understanding how to form this query? The entire `group_id` will not be known, the starting of the `group_id` will be `consumer_group` hence I'm using the wild card.

Comment: Your query should work. It should return time series, where current value more than average value of the same series over last 5 minutes. Check your query and it's both parts at Prometheus' `/graph` page (switch to graph tab) to see if query returns expected result, or even any result.

Comment: Also notice that this query should produce quite a lot of false alarms in case of a sudden short increase of message producing intensity.

Comment: "But this doesn't seem to work" - what do you mean by this? can you explain more on what part is not working?

Comment: @markalex is there a way I avoid false alarms like you mentioned?

Comment: With this exact approach - no. If produces puts 100000 messages into the queue at once, no softening of the rule will help. You'll need to base your alert on some other indicator. For example, combination of number of processed items and queue size. Or something like "queue has not shrinked for last 5 min". Depending on your situation.

Comment: Have you managed to find out why your query initially "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: Not yet, i get empty results for the query. I tried them individually as well and get empty result for the avg_over_time query as well as kafka_consumer_group_lag. I might be missing something here

Comment: And does to work without regex selector?